# OracleSQL: Retrieving the value of adjacents fields if value is empty

Tags: sql, oracle

I got a big table A and need to get the value of a filled adjacent field (with Code: K_P_1) within a group (Column: Key) if the current field (text) is null. A group does not necessarily have a field with Code K_P_1. I have many joins in my query and hope the following minimal example brings my problem closer.

My thoughs: I actually thought I could solve my problem through right outer joins, but I do not have any idea what key to combine. When I go over case statements, I'm missing the reference to the neighboring field.

My Table A:

```
select Key, Code, Text from A;

Key Code  Text  
11K K_P_1 text  
11K K_P_2 (null)
11K K_P_3 (null)    
12K K_P_1 text2
12K K_P_2 (null)
12K K_P_3 (null)
```

My intended View:

```
Key Code  Text   FamilyText
11K K_P_1 text   text
11K K_P_2 (null) text
11K K_P_3 (null) text   
12K K_P_1 text2  text2
12K K_P_2 (null) text2
12K K_P_3 (null) text2
```

Comment: I don't fully understand the question.  What if multiple keys have values and others are `NULL`?  What value do you want?  What value do you want if `'K_P_1'` doesn't exist?

Comment: If 'K_P_1' doesnt exist the result should be null. Multiple Keys are  impossible because of a restriction in the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use windowed function [FIRST_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions057.htm):

```
SELECT tab.*, 
       FIRST_VALUE(Text IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY Key ORDER BY Code) AS FamilyText
FROM tab;
```

Comment: wow, works fine. I did not think that would be so comfortable to solve, thanks!

Comment: @MavidDeyers Glad I could help. SQL is epxressive and powerful language :)

Comment: "ignore nulls" in this case does not required.

Answer (score 1):

```
with s (Key, Code, Text) as (
select '11K', 'K_P_1', 'text'  from dual union all
select '11K', 'K_P_2', null    from dual union all
select '11K', 'K_P_3', null    from dual union all
select '12K', 'K_P_1', 'text2' from dual union all
select '12K', 'K_P_2', null    from dual union all
select '12K', 'K_P_3', null    from dual)
select s.*, lag(text ignore nulls, 1, text) over (partition by key order by code) FamilyText
from s;

KEY CODE  TEXT  FAMIL
--- ----- ----- -----
11K K_P_1 text  text 
11K K_P_2       text 
11K K_P_3       text 
12K K_P_1 text2 text2
12K K_P_2       text2
12K K_P_3       text2

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: I prefer this answer based on what I can glean from the question.